# top: how to fix the "window entry #1 corrupt" error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, top, configure, ubuntu-20.04

I have a `~/.toprc` exactly like [the one here](https://gist.github.com/wesgarrison/1186426), and it has always been fine.

However, since I update my Ubuntu to 20.04 LTS from 18.04, I no longer able to run top with it any more. This is what I'm getting:

`top: window entry #1 corrupt, please delete '/home/myid/.toprc'`

I like to keep my colorful `~/.toprc`, anyone knows how to make it work again pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the exact same issue when upgrading.

The suggestion in [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1560695) did not give me the settings I used to have. The way I solved it was to simply start `top` on Ubuntu 16.04 in my case (I'd guess 18.04 works just as well) using my old `.toprc` and then just press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to make `top` save the current configuration which it will do in updated format that works on Ubuntu 20.04 as well.

Comment: Thanks! Welcome to SU, with my +25.

Answer (score 0):

From

**Make top look less ugly on Arch Linux**
https://gist.github.com/liuyigh/df3687186d4e8ad7d5e374aa6c8dcded

```
remove your ~/.toprc (if any)
start "top"
press z
press V
press 1
press y
press m m
press t t t
press W
```